# Rendering in asymptote fails for high-quality settings

Tags: asymptote, rendering

I used to render my images with Asymptote. Currently I am updating my graphics, e.g. my file from

https://github.com/JuliaManifolds/Manopt.jl/blob/master/tutorials/regression/regression_result3.asy

rendered like

[image]

but today with the same settings (just slightly different points/dots but nearly the same image) renders like

[image]

where I use `asy -render 4 -f png file.asy`.

Any help on why this is happening or what might be the reason? It worked a few months ago with exactly the same settings on exactly the same machine (Mac OS 13.0, Apple M1).

Sure it senders fine with `-render 0` but that image is very very very very tiny (230x230).

*edit* / *update* : Here is an MWE

```
import three;
import solids;unitsize(4cm);

currentprojection=perspective( camera = (1.0, 0.5, 0.5), target = (0.0, 0.0, 0.0) );
currentlight=nolight;

revolution S=sphere(O,0.995);
pen SpherePen = rgb(0.85,0.85,0.85)+opacity(0.6);
pen SphereLinePen = rgb(0.75,0.75,0.75)+opacity(0.6)+linewidth(0.5pt);
draw(surface(S), surfacepen=SpherePen, meshpen=SphereLinePen);

/*
  Colors
*/
pen pointStyle1 = rgb(0.0,0.4666666666666667,0.7333333333333333)+linewidth(3.5pt)+opacity(1.0);

/*
  Exported Points
*/
dot( (0.9837117687894378,-0.17755131744105618,0.0280479165019622), pointStyle1);
dot( (0.9838420262712789,-0.05982681995903209,-0.1687472042909554), pointStyle1);
dot( (-0.0917525024594581,0.20000514884698506,0.9754893227130282), pointStyle1);
dot( (0.07844742532720095,0.5643971870536215,0.8217674955274712), pointStyle1);
dot( (0.8640095918651447,-0.32042627848327054,0.3883483297535702), pointStyle1);
dot( (0.09891843208768877,-0.3385482932829229,0.9357351104391312), pointStyle1);
dot( (0.5391307236127518,0.6639024159319173,0.518238984423744), pointStyle1);
```

which renders on my machine (using `asy -render 4 -f png thisfile.asy`). as

[image: result of the MWE]

Comment: For this figure, I suggest writing code in Asymptote directly, not exporting from other drawing tools

Comment: It is a say file (just a little long to attach here), so I am not sure how I should write that directly? It is generated from an export that I wrote myself, but nothing too fancy, just a few dots and the sphere. I can try to narrow that down to an MWE the next days.

Comment: I did what I proposed to do, narrowed the example down to really just have a few dots and the code is also attached. And yes the code is created with an export function I wrote myself, but I hope it is short enough to see that it is no complicated code actually.

Comment: Instead of `unitsize`, can you not specify something like `size(1000,0)` with `-render 0` to get a 1000px wide png file? You specified `unitsize(4cm)` . Your image being about 2 units wide makes `4 / 2.54 * 72` pixels, which is why your `png` outputs has the size it is.

Comment: Nice idea, will try on my next export :) What does the `0` refer to? That it does keep aspect ratio?

Comment: Tried it and it is nicer to set a specific size, but yields the same problems.

Comment: Hi Ronny, did you have any luck fixing this? I believe I'm running into similar problems (also on Mac - I have slightly different but potentially related problems on Linux, where I can't compile without setting render to 0).

Comment: No, I still face the same problems.